# How to install a driver which does not have a installer, just object files

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, ethernet

I am using a USB2.0 to Ethernet driver from Plugable on my  Windows XP 2002 professional.
When I plugged it in, Windows XP though detected this hardware, it was not able to install driver for it. So i downloaded the driver package from asix website [here](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88772A_760_772_XP2K_32bit_Driver_v3.4.3.38_WHQL.zip)

When i unzip it I see these files in it:

ax88772.cat

Ax88772.inf

ax88772.sys

WdfCoInstaller01007.dll

history.txt (revision history for the driver)

How do I install this driver on my WinXP?

Do these files just need to be copied to  some specific folders i my windows installation folder: C:\Windows\

Is it ok to copy :

WdfCoInstaller01007.dll & Ax88772.inf to C:\Windows\system\   as I see some existing *.dll and *.inf files in that path?

And copy ax88772.sys to C:\Windows\system32  as I see some *.sys there?

What about the file ax88772.cat ?

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just copy them to system32, this won't get you what you want.

Goto your device manager(Windows key + Pause, then device manger), and select the new device you installed. It should be a yellow exclaimation point icon.

Right-click on the entry and open it. One of the tabs has an install driver button, click on that. Then navigate to where you unzipped the installation files, and select Ax88772.inf.

Pardon the vague instructions, its been a minute since I installed XP drivers. But this should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks. Have done this. After the installation the small yellow exclamation mark in Device manager seems to have gone away but looks like i need to reboot my PC, as still the ethernet port does not seem to work as the USB-Ethernet port is the one which connects me to internet. So will reboot and update.

Comment: glad I could help