# install USB2LAN Adapter drive which do not have exe file

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I want to install the usb2lan adapter driver to windows 7. facing two prblms: 
1. my system is unable to recognize the hardware
2. there is no exe file in the zip. it only consists of

Ax88772.inf

ax88772.sys

ax88772ex.cat

history.txt

WdfCoInstaller01007.dll

what all I need to do to install the driver and where to place these files??

Comment: The .inf is the device driver.  You can open the file in a text editor to verify the device supports Windows 7.  If you are running a 64-bit installation you won't be able to install the driver since its a 32-bit driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Ax88772.inf and select "Install" from the context menu.

Comment: This is not working. can you suggest some other alternative.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yeah...it says - "This type of installation is not supported"

Comment: Also my system is not recognizing the hardware.

Comment: Do you see an unrecognized device in device Manager? If not, the hardware may be defect. Otherwise see the device property to get the PCI ID of the device, and use the ID to search for drivers.

Comment: Yeah..Its showing unknown usb device in device manager. Earlier when I connected the device it showed the device in network adapters with a yellow exclaimation mark. then I performed the steps given in site "http://superuser.com/questions/543515/how-to-install-a-driver-which-does-not-have-a-installer-just-object-files". After that the system is not able to recognize the device.

Comment: It seems that the driver is not associated to the device. Check http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-device-not-recognized-in-windows-7/8106a712-a13e-4ca5-b82e-c3961cc254b1